# how can i use process monitor to figure out what's happening with permissions?

Tags: php, http, iis

I am trying to use this function in PHP `move_uploaded_File` to move a file to a different directory than the one it was uploaded to.

However, even though the user has enough rights (iusr / iis_iusrs) to upload the file, when the function `move_uploaded_file()` is run, nothing happens!

I'm running IIS 8 with php .

**How can I use process monitor to figure out what's happening with permissions?**

Answer (score 1):

well, you start capturing, perform the action that fails, stop your capture, and then filter the results to see what actions occured. you might want to Try [FileMon](http://www.sysinternals.com/Utilities/Filemon.html) instead. you can filter it by process to only see the IIS worker processes you want, and then by file to see whats going on.

That said, these tools are no replacement for debugging and logging. the php runtime is your best source for information on whats going down.